# What items to buy to enhance Nidalee's tankiness after the last "balance" patch?

Tags: league-of-legends

Back in the days when Nidalee had a nice armor/resist bonus when in [image: Cougar form] I only had to buy a [image: Kindlegem] and/or a [image: Haunting Guise] in order to survive jumping in and comboing:

[image: Pounce] **+** [image: Swipe] **+** [image: Takedown] enemies. Now Riot took the bonus away and I'm a bit puzzled what items should I buy to compensate for the squishiness and still retain the burst potential. Since Riot boosted [image: Swipe] I'm sure they had the intention to empower Nidalee's burst even more. What items can compensate for the lack of defensive stats?

**Important**: I play AP Nidalee because [image: Javelin Toss] is so much fun **and** nearly all of Nidalee's skills scale with AP.

Comment: Rod Of Ages for HP, Zhonya's for Armor, Abyssal for MR.  I would skip Abyssal unless against AP heavy team.  This is subjective, so I'm only going to comment.  There is no one true answer, though.

Comment: And just for reference to any champion, buying resistances if you are under 1700HP isn't cost-effective.  For the best effective HP, get to 1700 before throwing money into armor/MR

Comment: Right now I'm trying to experiment with an Icebourne Gauntlet/Zhonya's build, but I never make it far enough into the game to build either

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk I find Iceborn extremely weak on her - it just doesn't give enough AP for damage and it also doesn't give HP for tankiness, just armor. Unless it's basically your last buy I vote skip it, and even then there's probably better items to be getting Nidalee.

Comment: Rather than trying to assassinate/execute in cougar form, AP Nidalee should mostly be in Human form chugging spears and using cougar form to widen the distance for maximum damage or for escaping. Very rarely would you ever use Cougar form in a fight as AP Niadlee, unless you're certain you'll get away. Late game, doesn't matter how much resistance you get as an AP carry, if you're in the front line you'll melt. So it's best to avoid those kind of confrontation.

But if you insist, zhonyas works wonders. I wouldn't recommend getting Abyssal as your spears won't benefit from it.

Comment: @Shelby.S Her cougar form is like Quinn's ult. You gotta know when to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to get tankier. Rod of Ages is a good one for most casters, as is Zhonya's Hourglass. If you need MR, and are spamming a lot of abilities, Athene's Unholy Grail is always a good choice. Since Nidalee often is poking down high-health enemies in preparation for a burst, Liandry's Torment might be a good call as well, giving a bit of health. Getting Will of the Ancients (or, preferably, convincing an ally who'll jump with you to get it) can also add a surprising amount of survivability to Nidalee, especially if she already has some resistances.

Answer (score 0):

Buy Zhonya, Rylai that can be really useful.
Yet I saw a really good Nida who had bought a Warmog...